# Deploy Docker app on Elastic Beanstalk with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need help please.

I'm trying to deploy a Dockerfile on elastic beanstalk. My code works fine, the environment is created without a hitch, but when I go to the web interface, the sample is displayed instead of my application :

[image]

I don't understand, because if I do the manipulations manually, my application deploys correctly but it's not the case with Terraform...

Here is my code:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "game-2048" {
  bucket = "2048-${random_pet.petname.id}"
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "game-2048" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.game-2048.id
  key    = "beanstalk/Dockerfile"
  source = "Dockerfile"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version" "game-2048" {
  name        = "2048-version"
  application = "2048-game"
  description = "application version"
  bucket      = aws_s3_bucket.game-2048.id
  key         = aws_s3_object.game-2048.id
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "game-2048" {
  name        = "2048-game"
  description = "Elastic Beanstlak app for 2048"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "env-2048" {
  name                = "2048-game"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.game-2048.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2023 v4.0.0 running Docker"

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name = "IamInstanceProfile"
    value = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment"
    name = "ServiceRole"
    value = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
  }

}

# To print the env CNAME after creation
output "env_cname" {
  value = "http://${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.env-2048.cname}"
}
```

Have I forgotten anything important to make this work?

And this is my the events from the environment on my aws console :

[image]

On GitHub I found someone else's project trying to deploy an application on Elastic Beanstalk (a Python application). After comparing our codes I don't think I missed any important parameters but yet his application deploys correctly. Here's his repository: https://github.com/devenes/elastic-beanstalk-ap

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Well the error is clear. You are missing the role. Did you create the role as written in the error message?

Comment: Hello @Marcin thanks for your response.

Are you talking about the warnings displayed in the events console ? Yes I created the role and put it in my code so I don't think this is the problem here (correct me if I'm wrong). When I deployed manually my app I had the same warnings and like I said my code is working but the only things that is not working is the deployment of the dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved after a deep investigation. I was missing the "version_label" argument in the "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" resource.

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "env-2048" {
  name                = "2048-game"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.game-2048.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Amazon Linux 2023 v4.0.0 running Docker"
  version_label       = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version.game-2048.name
```

When you want to upload an object to the environment, this parameter is required (look at the screen):

[image]

Since I hadn't declared this argument, the sample application was deployed instead of my container.